# Maya MEL script to create implicit surfaces

Tags: scripting, maya, graphic, mel

I am trying to write a MEL script that will draw simple implicit surfaces in Maya. I have had a search online but could not find that much on the topic.

Does anyone know how to create a MEL script to draw a simple implicit surface in Maya?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:
http://www.german-efficiency.com/maya/readme.html